# ubuntu18.04 install nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I know it has been asked for many times, but I have almost tried all of them but fail. I have Ubuntu 18.04 on my PC. It has 2 Nvidia cards, Tesla K80. I want to properly install a driver so that I can use genymotion on it. I have tried:

1. Using `Nvidia-xxx.run` file to install
2. Using `cuda-xxx.run` file to install
3. The command `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
4. The command `apt install nvidia-xxx`
5. Choosing another driver in the Additional Drivers tab in Software & Updates (in the graphical user interface)

After operation, I can use `nvidia-smi` but not `nvidia-settings`. `prime-select query` shows `nvidia`, but the system detail interface still shows the *open source driver*, and I can't use genymotion (black screen). I have reinstalled the system several times. Could anyone help?

Comment: If there are two K80 in `nvidia-smi` outputs, your driver was installed properly. Black screen in genymotion may not caused by the nvidia driver.